# CodeIgniter strange behaviour with sess_destroy

Tags: codeigniter

What is wrong in this code?

The session variable "user" has the id of the user logged. It's set on login process.

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user",$user->id);
```

This code always show the error page and perform the session destroy!!!why?

```
if ( !$this->session->userdata("user"))
{
   $error = "User do logout without been logged [" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ."]" ;
   log_message('error', $error);
   show_error($error);
}
else
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```

If I comment **$this->session->sess_destroy()**  it works, the session is not destroy and the error is not shown

Comment: I have found unexpected behavior when trying to use the CI session library for an online chat application. I finally switched to using native PHP sessions. I suspect you have found such a bug. Good catch; it might provide some useful insight.

Answer (score 1):

Your function says: "If the user is not logged in, show the error message and log the error, otherwise log the user out with sess_destroy()"

So if you visit the page and you are not logged in, you see the error. If you visit the page, and YOU ARE logged in, the function calls sess_destroy and logs you out.

---

Clarification: Your code only allows for 1 user state: logged out--that is the only way there will be any output on the page. If someone who is logged in visits the page, they are logged out immediately.

```
if($this->session->userdata('email')){
    //the user is logged in
    echo "HELLO USER, YOU ARE LOGGED IN!";
}else{
    //you don't need session_destroy because 
    //they won't get here with a session to be destroyed
    redirect('/home');
}
```

---

Further clarification: I tested this on a fresh install of Codeigniter, and it behaves as I explained.

Modifying the default welcome controller to save time:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');

    }

    function index()
    {

        $this->session->set_userdata("user","1234");
        echo "userdata set to: ".$this->session->userdata("user"). "<br>";
        echo "<a href='welcome/checksess'>check session</a>";
    }

    function checksess()
    {


        if ( !$this->session->userdata("user"))
        {
           $error = "User do logout without been logged [" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ."]" ;
           log_message('error', $error);
           show_error($error);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "userdata: ".$this->session->userdata("user"). " about to be destroyed with sess_destroy<br>";
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            echo "<a href='checksess'>check session again after sess_destroy (refresh this page)</a>";
        }
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

When you visit welcome/index it sets the session data. When you click the link to checksess, checksess echo's the userdata then calls sess_destroy. Now if you refresh checksess, userdata is NOT set (because of sess_destroy) and you see the error "User do logout without been logged..."

There is nothing in the code you provided to explain the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: No, this would be the correct behaviour... if I'm logged in and I visit the page I get the error and session destroy. it's like execute the page twice. I don't know why but it's happening...

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I updated the answer with an example.. but the short of it is your code only allows for the user to be logged out.

Comment: I know...it's very strange but this happens I've done test in deeply. My steps are 1) Login 2) launch the user page 3) logout 4) I get error log and the session is destroyed (I know the session is destroyed because of I can see it on CI profiler and I can't see the step 2

Comment: If I insert an sleep of 4 seconds before session destroy it works

Comment: I also know that I can simplified only doing $this->session->sess_destroy() but I'm interesting in knowing what is happening... –

Comment: There is something else going on in your code.. perhaps a redirect, or refresh.. I'll update my answer again.